# How to set the a variable in Angular template within ng-repeat on first element

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array that is load through ngResource. Each object within the array is three level deep (object which contains an array of objects which in turn has an array of objects) like so:

```
ngResource = [
    object1 = {...},
    object2 = {...},
    object3 = {
        ...
        array = [
            object1 = {...}
            object2 = {...}
            object3 = {
                ...
                obj1 = {...},
                obj2 = {...},
                obj3 = {
                    ...
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'd like a ng-repeat to create a Angular Ui accordion for each object within a three level deep loop, which is accomplished by:

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="category in categories">
    ...
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="subcat in category.subcategories">
        ...
            <accordion-group ng-repeat="product in subcat.products">
            ...
```

All works fine. What I'd like is to make the first accordion in each loop open. Angular UI accordion has the property `is-open` that can set on the template like so:

```
<accordion-group ... is-open="true">
...
```

If I loop through the objects within my controller and add a property `isOpen` on the first object, it doesn't work because the initial array (ngResource, which I gave it this name in here to demonstrate how the data was obtained) doesn't load until later after the page loaded.

How can I dynamically add a property (preferably in the template) on the first object only?

I've also tried using `ng-if` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    ...
    <div ng-if="$first"><span ng-init="category.isOpen = true"></span></div>
```

But that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngRepeat` exposes some other special variables like `$first`.

Bind this to the `is-open` property:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="subcat in category.subcategories" is-open="$first">
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you!